Mkdocs-material hide toc and navigation bar but preserve padding(margins)
Is it possible to hide navigation bar and toc in mkdocs-material but keep margins as on other pages?
To be more specific I'm adding the following instructions before content of .md file:
---
hide:   
  - navigation
  - toc
---

I'm expecting that margins will be preserved.
